# How to send data from nodejs child to command prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I need a way to write a string to the child application. From the child’s point of view it looks just like someone typed the text from a terminal.

```
CommandHandler.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
    // sleep.sleep(2)
    if (data.indexOf("Press a to answer or h to reject call") >= 0) {
        sleep.sleep(1)
        console.log("ANSWER CALL FOR USER NAME : " + (user_name) + '\n')
    }
});
```

Where I need to send `a` to terminal

Comment: You could consider using https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs which enable your application to send command cross platforms (Windows/Linux/OS X).

Comment: @GibboK, I need to send a string to child just 'a'